# Optimizing dask for a complex ecological model

Tags: python, performance, optimization, dask, distributed-computing

I am trying to run an ecological model in a Dask environment. Though I am not entirely content with the speed of the calculations. I am running it locally on a single machine. Are there some quick improvements noticeable from the code below:

```
from dask_open import dask_slice
from dask.distributed import Client
from calc_si_no_bloom import calc_si_no_bloom
import time
import dask
client = Client(processes=False)
start_time = time.clock()
path_tx_01 = r'C:\Users\eobs_data\tx_mean_0.1_hom.nc'
path_tn_01 = r'C:\Users\eobs_data\tn_mean_0.1_hom.nc'
mindask, latlon, latitude = dask_slice(path_tn_01, 1980, 2018,250, -25, 45, 34, 72)
maxdask, latlon, latitude = dask_slice(path_tx_01, 1980, 2018,250, -25, 45, 34, 72)
lazy_results = dask.delayed(calc_si_no_bloom)(mindask,maxdask,latitude) 
# mindask and maxdask have a chunksize of (1, 20000, 250) and 39 chunks 
lfmtx, lfrz = lazy_results.compute()
print(time.clock() - start_time, "seconds for model run")
```

dask_slice function:

```
def dask_slice(path, startyear, endyear, ndays, latmin, latmax, lonmin, lonmax):
data = xr.open_dataarray(path)
data = data.sel(time=slice('1950-01-01','2018-12-31'))
data = data.sel(latitude=slice(latmin,latmax))
data = data.sel(longitude=slice(lonmin,lonmax))
data = data.stack(latlon=['latitude','longitude'])
latlon = list(data.latlon.values) #latlon[45693] = (49.875,14.875)
latitude = data.latitude.values
group = data.groupby('time.year')
list_group = list(group)
dictio = dict((x,y) for x,y in list_group)
lijst = []
for i in range(startyear,endyear+1):
    year = dictio[i].values[:ndays,:]
    lijst.append(year)
daskarray = daar.stack(lijst, axis=0)
daskarray_F = tempunits(daskarray, 'C', 'F')
daskarray = np.swapaxes(daskarray_F,1,2)
return daskarray, latlon, latitude
```

The model itself (calc_si_no_bloom) calculates cumulative temperature from minimum and maximum temperature. It calls a number of different functions, all of which include many for loops. Is there more sense in changing the structure of the functions that comprise the model or am I implementing Dask inefficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The first step to improving performance of your code is usually to measure what is slow.  I recommend reading through Dask's documentation on [Understanding Performance](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html) and then following some of the suggestions there.

After doing that work, if you have more specific questions then I recommend posting again with a more specific question (SO is rarely used for generic "help me improve my code" queries)

Comment: Thank you, will use these tools to check the performance! In the mean time I found out that while running the model the jupyter notebook tab repeatedly mentioned IOStream.flush timed out. I couldnt find much online about this line of code, do you have any idea what it means and what could cause it?